# Struts 1 - Calling more actions via one post without altering struts-config

Tags: java, websphere, struts, java-6, legacy

I'm working on a legacy app (struts 1, own framework, java 6, on WebSphere 7) where I need to change the behavior of an operation.

Let's call them (1) *CopyItem*, (2) *AlterItem*, (3) *MarkAsCopied*.

A button called one service which needs to be replaced with three other services. 
Depending on the result of the first one, invoke the second one and so on.
I want to navigate in the end where the first one would take me (so it would look like the original behavior from user point of view).

Initially I thought I wrap every parameter I need into a form, POST it, and then on the Java side, I would call action execute for each service. Technically from *CopyItemAction.execute()* of *CopyItem* I would call *AlterItem* and *MarkAsCopied* executes as well.

I feel that this is pretty far from a clean solution.

Do you have a better idea, how to do this?

Comment: The normal way to do this is to process the action via business logic: you don't call additional actions, you call additional business logic from wherever you're currently calling the current business logic. struts-config has nothing to do with this--you're not trying to change what happens on the client side, you're changing what happens on the back end. I don't see the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit? If I want to call two services while staying on the first page, how do I wire them together?

Comment: You make the calls to the business logic on the back end. I mean, technically you could coordinate all that through Ajax, but I wouldn't, and would again defer to doing the work on the back end.

Comment: So you can touch the Java code but not the Struts config? I don't understand why. Or is it just that you can't/don't want to change the URLs the user sees? You can have a Struts action forward directly to another Struts action.

Comment: But in general, don't do that--it mixes concerns and will increase the amount of effort required to debug issues. It's the same reason we tend to discourage action chaining in Struts 2.

Comment: @dbreaux I can touch the frontend code, so I can modify the struts config, but that is configured for different beans with different properties so would need to create a new one, looking for a lazier way.
Can I redirect a struts action to another one without navigating away from the screen?

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right, and I agree, but I need to stick to this way, this is the explicit request of the business.

Comment: Redirecting by definition leaves the screen. That's why I said Ajax, but that's still a road to a big mess. You need to find out the reason this is the "explicit request" of business because it's most likely they don't know what they're talking about, don't understand the ramifications, and are having an XY-problem moment.

Comment: Ajax is not a bad idea at all, but how do I prevent redirection and achieve synchronization with that? 
Service (b) Needs to run after service (a) has finished successfully, etc.
After that the page should redirect the user, but I can manage that.

Comment: I remember that recommendation against action chaining, but we had several cases where it was the simplest way to do what we wanted, and best I can tell we never had major problems from doing so. But really, I was suggesting it here because it seems like the OP just needs to hack something to minimally address a specific need. And it's not like Struts 1 code needs to be super forward-thinking these days, is it?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did it via synchronized Ajax. Which is definitely bad practice, so I do not recommend if you have the access on the backend code. However in my case now it turned out to be a working not-that-ugly solution. Based on Dave Newton's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) proposal.

**Keep that in mind the struts actions are still called according to the configuration defined in struts-config.xml.**

I created the js function below and invoked the services with the specified forms one by one. This way a form (POST) submit calls the struts action, but doesn't navigate away. After they run successfully I redirected the page.

```
    function submitForm(form) {
        if (form !== null && form !== undefined) {

            let formData = new FormData(form);
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), false);

            var successResponse = false;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    successResponse = xhr.status == 200;
                }
            }

            xhr.send(formData);
            return successResponse;
        }
    }
```

In conclusion: this is not a recommended solution, but if you're in such a situation like me, then it works.